# Mysql many-to-many relationship problem between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, many-to-many

first of all, I apologize if I was wrong with the title. I could not find how to state the problem I was experiencing. I'm working on a Laravel project. I have two tables called orders and order_items.

Mysql Tables:

**orders**

- order_id
- order_date
- order_customer_id

**order_items**

- order_item_id
- order_id
- order_item_product_id
- order_piece

The image I want to reach:

[image]

I want to show the user the orders in his account and the products belonging to that order in the form of an accordion menu. There may be more than one order on the page. Naturally the same order is repeated multiple times when I try it with leftJoin. I could not understand if this is a problem I need to solve on the mysql side or the php side. Can you give me a guide on this matter?

**My Current Code:**

```
$query = Order::query();
$query->where('order_customer_id', $customerID);
$query->leftJoin('order_items', 'orders.order_id','=','order_items.order_id');
$data['orderList'] = $query->get();
return view('pages.orders.index', $data);
```

Comment: Please, show your query, what you get from it, and what you want to get instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I added my code to my question.

Comment: Where's the problem exactly? What is the outcome of your query?

Comment: Why are you using `leftJoin` instead of a relation ? It would be `Order::with('items')->all()`, something like that, and your problem is solved. Share your 2 models so we can help you with the relations. Also take into account that you are not following standard relation's naming, your table should be called `items`, and in your columns have `id`, `order_id`, `product_id` and `price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your database, i see its ***one to many relationship*** (Not many to many as your title said).

You can just create relation at your ***model***

***OrderItem.php***

```
public function order(){
    $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
}
```

***Order.php***

```
public function orderitem(){
    $this->hasMany(orderitem::class);
}
```

At ***controller***, get the Order

```
$orders = Order::with('orderitems')->get();
return view('yourview',compact('orders'))
```

At ***view***

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
   {{$oder->name}}
   @foreach($order->orderitem as $orderItem)
       {{$orderItem->name}}
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: If you want many to many, you create 1 more pivot table like Order_OrderItem, then have order_id and order_item_id column